# Not able to call .NET Core API with JWT token

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I have an endpoint like this:

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("get_token_step2")]
public ActionResult<TokenResponseModel> AuthenticateStep2([FromBody] AuthenticateModel authenticateModel)
{
    tokenResponseModel token = null;

    try
    {
        tokenResponseModel = _authenticationService.AuthenticateUserWithSchoolId(authenticateModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return Ok(tokenResponseModel);
}
```

I tried to call this API with a JWT token, but it's not hitting to the endpoint. But if I add the `[AllowAnonymous]`, it's hitting the endpoint.

I tried to call in 2 ways like this:

Attempt #1:

[image]

Attempt #2:

[image]

Please let me know better way to call. Thanks

Comment: Both those Postman screenshots result in the same call! Chances are that the token is invalid. How did you get the token? How old is the token? I'm guessing that you get a 403 or 401 response.

Comment: Token is valid only , generated before 1 minute of that api call and i'm getting 404 error code , but if add AllowAnonymous it's hitting to the same endpoint

Comment: Weird, I wouldn't expect a 404 for an authentication/authorization failure! Can you show us the code where you have added token auth in to your project?

Comment: sry  ?  token auth ? I've created step1 endpoint there i'm generating token , then i've add [authorize] token for step2 endpoint which is like i've added in the question